# Locust randomly fails

Tags: locust

I am attempting to perform load testing, but the test results are inconsistent. While load testing generally succeeds on my local machine, it fails intermittently on the CI environment.

I run below bash script to run locust file after running the API.

```bash
function loadTesting() {
    # check if locust installed
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v locust -V)" ]; then
        if ! [ -x "$(command -v pip3 -V)" ]; then
            warn_msg "pip3 is not installed. Installing..."
            apt install python3-pip
        fi
        warn_msg "Locust is not installed. Installing..."
        pip3 install locust
    fi
    local HOST=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    local CONCURRENT=500
    local RATE=500
    local DURATION=10
    locust -f ${ROOT_DIR}/load-testing/locust.py \
                         --host ${HOST}          \
                         --headless              \
                         --users=${CONCURRENT}   \
                         --spawn-rate=${RATE}    \
                         --run-time=${DURATION}s \
                         --reset-stats           \
                         --only-summary
}
```

And here is my locust file

```py
from locust import task, between, FastHttpUser
import string
import random
import time
import datetime

WAIT_TIME_MIN = 0.1
WAIT_TIME_MAX = 0.5

h = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
}

random.seed()

class LoadTest(FastHttpUser):
    wait_time = between(WAIT_TIME_MIN, WAIT_TIME_MAX)
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base_path = None

    def generate_random_string(self, min_name_size=2, max_name_size=20) -> str:
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        string_size = random.randint(min_name_size, max_name_size)
        generated_string = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(string_size))
        return generated_string

    def generate_random_dob(self) -> str:
        d = random.randint(1, int(time.time()))
        return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    @task(1)
    def get_all(self):
        self.client.get(url=self.base_path, headers=h)

    @task(1)
    def get_one_by_id(self):
        random_id = self.random_user_id()
        self.client.get(url=f"{self.base_path}/by-id/{random_id}", headers=h)

    @task(1)
    def get_one_by_email(self):
        random_email = self.random_user_mail()
        self.client.get(url=f"{self.base_path}/by-email/{random_email}", headers=h)

    @task(20)
    def post_request(self):
        self.client.post(url=self.base_path, json=self._generate_post_data(), headers=h)

    @task(4)
    def put_request(self):
        request_path, request_data = self._generate_put_data()
        self.client.put(url=request_path, json=request_data, headers=h)


class TeacherProcess(LoadTest):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base_path = "/api/v1/teacher"
        self.teacher_mails = []
        self.counter = 0

    def on_start(self):
        self.client.post(url=self.base_path,
                         json=self._generate_post_data(),
                         headers=h)
    
    def random_user_mail(self) -> str:
        return random.choice(self.teacher_mails)
    
    def random_user_id(self) -> int:
        return random.randint(1, self.counter)

    def on_stop(self):
        for email in self.teacher_mails:
            self.client.delete(url=f"{self.base_path}/by-email/{email}", headers=h)

    def _generate_post_data(self) -> dict:
        request_data = {
            "name" : self.generate_random_string(),
            "email": f"{self.generate_random_string()}@{self.generate_random_string()}.{self.generate_random_string()}",
            "dob": self.generate_random_dob()
        }
        self.teacher_mails.append(request_data["email"])
        self.counter += 1

        return request_data

    def _generate_put_data(self) -> (str | dict):
        request_data = {
            "name": self.generate_random_string(),
            "email": f"{self.generate_random_string()}@{self.generate_random_string()}.{self.generate_random_string()}",
            "dob": self.generate_random_dob()
        }

         # select random email on db
        random_teacher_mail_on_db = random.choice(self.teacher_mails)
        # delete randomly selected email from list
        self.teacher_mails.remove(random_teacher_mail_on_db)
        # add new email to the list
        self.teacher_mails.append(request_data["email"])

        return f"{self.base_path}/{random_teacher_mail_on_db}", request_data


class StudentProcess(LoadTest):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base_path = "/api/v1/student"
        self.student_mails = []
        self.counter = 0

    def on_start(self):
        self.client.post(url=self.base_path,
                         json=self._generate_post_data(),
                         headers=h)
        
    def random_user_mail(self) -> str:
        return random.choice(self.student_mails)
    
    def random_user_id(self) -> int:
        return random.randint(1, self.counter)
    
    def on_stop(self):
        for email in self.student_mails:
            self.client.delete(url=f"{self.base_path}/by-email/{email}", headers=h)

    def _generate_post_data(self) -> dict:
        request_data = {
            "name": self.generate_random_string(),
            "email": f"{self.generate_random_string()}@{self.generate_random_string()}.{self.generate_random_string()}",
            "dob": self.generate_random_dob()
        }

        self.student_mails.append(request_data["email"])
        self.counter += 1

        return request_data
    
    def _generate_put_data(self) -> (str | dict):
        request_data = {
            "name": self.generate_random_string(),
            "email": f"{self.generate_random_string()}@{self.generate_random_string()}.{self.generate_random_string()}",
            "dob": self.generate_random_dob()
        }

        # select random email on db
        random_student_mail_on_db = random.choice(self.student_mails)
        # delete randomly selected email from list
        self.student_mails.remove(random_student_mail_on_db)
        # add new email to the list
        self.student_mails.append(request_data["email"])

        return f"{self.base_path}/{random_student_mail_on_db}", request_data
```

I expect the test to consistently pass without modifying any parameters. However, the test results vary on the CI (GitHub Action), with some cases passing and others failing.

Here are two examples where the code remains the same, but the difference lies in the timing of the CI runs:

1. [Failed test](https://github.com/serdarakyol/spring-boot-app/actions/runs/4967612727/jobs/8889752117)
2. [Passed test](https://github.com/serdarakyol/spring-boot-app/actions/runs/4967711016/jobs/8889866935)

Comment: Locust looks like it's working fine. You're getting a 404 on one of your calls that you will need to look into.

Comment: @Solowalker I am not making any changes to the code but as you can see in the examples, the test sometimes passes, sometimes fails. What might be the problem?

Comment: You will need to investigate why you're getting a 404 on a call sometimes. Add logging to Locust and your server to see what's going on. A hunch would be a race condition where your server is taking longer to process your posts than Locust is waiting before sending the delete for that user.

Comment: @Solowalker If that would be the problem, I'd get some failures on my local machine. Isn't it?